# How to structure httr POST request to return site data?

Tags: r, http-post, httr

I'm having trouble pulling data from the following website. If I go to the long_url via my browser I can see the table I want to scrape, but if I call the url from within R using httr, I'm either not getting the data returned to me, or I'm not understanding how it's being returned to me.

```
base_url <- "http://web1.ncaa.org/stats/exec/records"
long_url <- "http://web1.ncaa.org/stats/exec/records?academicYear=2014&sportCode=MFB&orgId=721"

library(XML)
library(httr)
library(rvest) # devtools::install_github("hadley/rvest")
```

The results of these POST requests look identical to me,

```
doc <- POST(base_url, query = list(academicYear = "2014", sportCode = "MFB",
                                         orgId = "721"))
doc <- POST(long_url)

class(doc)
```

Both POST requests return a status code of 200, and the class of doc is "HTMLInternalDocument" and "XMLInternalDocument" which is the normal R object that allows me to scrape the pages. But then the following rvest and XML functions come up empty, even though I know there is a table at the url.

```
 table <- html_nodes(doc, css = "td")
 table <- readHTMLTable(doc)
```

Could someone help explain to me what my httr request is missing? I also tried a GET request with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are encountering here is actually a pretty common problem. `httr` uses `RCurl` for the heavy lifting. The default user_agent header sent in a GET or POST request by `RCurl` is `NULL`, which frequently confuses scripts. This is why you get different results from your browser and `httr(...)`. If you spoof a meaningful user agent, you get the results you want.

```
base_url <- "http://web1.ncaa.org/stats/exec/records"
ua       <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
library(httr)
library(XML)
doc <- POST(base_url, 
            query = list(academicYear = "2014", sportCode = "MFB",orgId = "721"),
            user_agent(ua))

html <- content(doc, useInternalNodes=T)
df.list <- readHTMLTable(html)
df      <- df.list[[4]]
head(df)
#    Opponent  Game Date Air ForceScore OppScore  Loc Neutral SiteLocation GameLength Attend
# 1   Colgate 08/31/2013             38       13 Home                               - 32,095
# 2  Utah St. 09/07/2013             20       52 Home                               - 32,716
# 3 Boise St. 09/13/2013             20       42 Away                               - 36,069
# 4   Wyoming 09/21/2013             23       56 Home                               - 35,389
# 5    Nevada 09/28/2013             42       45 Away                               - 24,545
# 6      Navy 10/05/2013             10       28 Away                               - 38,225
```

Note also that this website uses tables for just about everything, so `readHTMLTable(...)` actually returns a list of 4 data frames. The 4th is the one you want.

You don't need `rvest`.

Comment: FYI httr does set the user agent.

Comment: @hadley Really? To what? In that case, any idea why OP's code does not work, but setting the user agent explicitly does?

Comment: It sets it to something like `httr/RCurl/R`, so if the server is doing UA sniffing it doesn't match anything known.